# How to open interactive gnuplot window from a bash script

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a file using gnuplot from within a bash script. For this I used the following command:

```
gnuplot --persist -e "plot file1.dat"
```

It shows the plot in a window but I want to look at the data points by zooming in. But this is not allowed. How can I plot the file so that I can zoom in the plot just like while plotting from inside gnuplot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [GNUPlot manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/documentation.html),

> Depending on the terminal type, some mousing operations may still be possible
> in the persistent window.  However operations like zoom/unzoom that require
> redrawing the plot are not possible because the main program has exited. If you
> want to leave a plot window open and fully mouseable after creating the plot,
> for example when running gnuplot from a script file rather than interactively,
> see pause mouse close.

Reading the "Pause mouse close" section, one finds the answer:

```
gnuplot --persist -e 'plot "file1.dat"; pause mouse close'
```

As you already know, you can now use Ctrl-WheelUp and Ctrl-WheelDown to zoom, as well as selecting a rectangular area
with the right button, as disclosed in the Scrolling and Zoom sections of the
manual.